# вылетает на InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); как решить проблему?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

вылетает на 
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
как решить проблему?

```
try {

    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(lnk)
            .openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// получаем ответ
try {
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String bfr_st;
    while ((bfr_st = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(bfr_st);
    }

    ansver = sb.toString();
    ansver = ansver.substring(0, ansver.indexOf("]") + 1);

    is.close(); // закроем поток
    br.close(); // закроем буфер

}
```

Comment: Что значит вылетает? Получаете эксепшен? Если эксепшен, то надо его привести.

Comment: Нет, экзепшен не вылетает, открывается белый фон и зависает, запрашивает подождать отклика приложения или закрыть.
а в logcat debug выводить эту строку  InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

Comment: Попробуйте `conn.setReadTimeout();` и `conn.setConnectTimeout();` поставить на 4000 вместо ваших значений.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не приложили лог ошибки, так что можно лишь гадать о том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться в сеть из основного потока и словили [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Решается это обращением в сеть из неосновного потока через Loader, AsynkTask или IntentService или прямым созданием нового потока.